# Is there a way to add a pseudo element after a text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is it possible to add pseudo **::after** after a specific text?

currently I have:

```
<div class="radio_button">
 <label for="button_1">
  ::before
  button 1 text
 </label>
```

I need to add **::after**  after button 1 text

Comment: No. At least not with pure CSS (unless you'll wrap the text with some HTML element)

Comment: Yes you can, just use `label::after { content: 'Your text here'; }`, if the text should appear in the `<label>` element. However, if you want to insert the element **after and outside the `<label>` element**, no you can't.

Comment: well, assuming that text is in the only thing in the element, it's just the same to add `:after` to the label itself, wouldn't make a difference in that regard, but if you're saying *only when that text == button 1 text* than it is possible since you tagged the question with javascript

Comment: Both `::before` and `::after` seem to be badly named.  They don't add content before/after the element, they both add content before/after the element's children, ie **inside** the element *"In CSS, `::after` creates a pseudo-element that is the last child of the selected element"* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after

Comment: @terry thank you!, yes that was what I needed to do, I had to add ::after inside the **<label>**

Comment: @Terry please add this as an answer so it can be upvoted.  OP has confirmed it is to appear inside the label

Comment: @Josh Glad to be able to help! I've added my comment as an answer with additional clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little more elaboration from my comment: you can simply use the `::after` pseudo-selector on your `<label>` element and specify the content. This has the effect of appending the content inside the element. Note that the `::after` pseudo-selector injects content into your element, instead of appending it *after* the element.

Here is a proof-of-concept example:

```css
.radio_button label::after {
  content: 'Appended content';
  
  /* For visuals only */
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="radio_button">
  <label for="button_1">
    button 1 text
  </label>
</div>
```